# How to invert the printed 'tirangle' output in a nested loop function

Tags: python

so for something like this:

```
    for j in range(n): 
         for i in range(j+1): 
         print(i, end = ' ')
```

It would print:

```
    0 
    0 1 
    0 1 2 
    0 1 2 3 
    0 1 2 3 4
```

How can i invert it to look like this:

```
    0 1 2 3 4
    1 2 3 4
    2 3 4
    3 4
    4
```

Comment: man. This aint Stackoverflow Question. Its like 1st day python class home assignment.

Comment: Why'd you delete your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102958/learning-java-object-patterns-using-jframe)? I was trying to post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to count down in the outer loop instead of up. Use

```
for j in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
```

instead of `for j in range(n)` to count from `n - 1` to `0` instead of from `0` to `n-1`

#### Edit (following the question edit)

Your inner loop should be counting up from `j` to `n - 1`. Then, you also won't need to invert the outer loop:

```
for j in range(n):
    for i in range(j, n): # From `j` to `n - 1`
        print(i, end=' ')
    print() # for the newline
```

Comment: THanks Hlt. This is definitely working. sorry i should have been more clear. Please look at "how can i invert it to look like this: above. I am going to edit it. Thanks.

Comment: with i range to (j,n) the triangle is not inverted anymore

Comment: True. Fixed it (with the inner loop like that, you do not need to invert the outer loop)

Comment: Thank you sir. i would appreciate +1 for the question or else i am getting banned. Thanks again.